# How to parse an xml file in python which has identical sub tags?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BioSampleSet>
  <BioSample accession="SAMN01347139" id="1347139" submission_date="2012-09-21T22:44:26.843" last_update="2012-09-21T22:44:26.843" publication_date="2012-09-21T22:44:26.843" access="controlled-access">
    <Ids>
      <Id is_primary="1" db="BioSample">SAMN01347139</Id>
      <Id db="dbGaP" is_hidden="1" db_label="Sample name">44-21834</Id>
    </Ids>
    <Description>
      <Title>DNA sample from a human male participant in the dbGaP study "Framingham SHARe Thyroid and Hormone Data"</Title>
      <Organism taxonomy_name="Homo sapiens" taxonomy_id="9606"/>
    </Description>
    <Owner>
      <Name abbreviation="NCBI"/>
    </Owner>
    <Models>
      <Model>Generic</Model>
    </Models>
    <Package display_name="Generic">Generic.1.0</Package>
    <Attributes>
      <Attribute display_name="gap accession" harmonized_name="gap_accession" attribute_name="gap_accession">phs000044</Attribute>
      <Attribute display_name="submitter handle" harmonized_name="submitter_handle" attribute_name="submitter handle">Framingham_SHARe</Attribute>
      <Attribute display_name="biospecimen repository" harmonized_name="biospecimen_repository" attribute_name="biospecimen repository">Framingham_SHARe</Attribute>
      <Attribute display_name="study name" harmonized_name="study_name" attribute_name="study name">Framingham SHARe Thyroid and Hormone Data</Attribute>
      <Attribute display_name="biospecimen repository sample id" harmonized_name="biospecimen_repository_sample_id" attribute_name="biospecimen repository sample id">21834</Attribute>
      <Attribute display_name="submitted sample id" harmonized_name="submitted_sample_id" attribute_name="submitted sample id">21834</Attribute>
      <Attribute display_name="submitted subject id" harmonized_name="submitted_subject_id" attribute_name="submitted subject id">21834</Attribute>
      <Attribute display_name="gap sample id" harmonized_name="gap_sample_id" attribute_name="gap_sample_id">105542</Attribute>
      <Attribute display_name="gap subject id" harmonized_name="gap_subject_id" attribute_name="gap_subject_id">28577</Attribute>
      <Attribute display_name="sex" harmonized_name="sex" attribute_name="sex">male</Attribute>
      <Attribute display_name="analyte type" harmonized_name="analyte_type" attribute_name="analyte type">DNA</Attribute>
      <Attribute display_name="subject is affected" harmonized_name="subject_is_affected" attribute_name="subject is affected"/>
      <Attribute display_name="gap consent code" harmonized_name="gap_consent_code" attribute_name="gap_consent_code">1</Attribute>
      <Attribute display_name="gap consent short name" harmonized_name="gap_consent_short_name" attribute_name="gap_consent_short_name">GRU</Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Status when="2012-09-21T22:44:26.843" status="suppressed"/>
  </BioSample>
</BioSampleSet>
```

I want to parse the above given xml file programatically. I tried using lxml, but I'm facing issues when it comes to extracting the key and values in `<Attributes>` tag since all the sub tags are named as **Attribute**. Anybody have any suggestions.
I tried splitting the text using "Attributes" as the regex, but since the entire file is a single line the resulting list is a list of alphabets from the specified section.
I am using python. And the number of `<Attribute>` tags may vary from time to time.
I'm currently using the below code:

```
from lxml import objectify 
import Bio.Entrez as Entrez
meta_data = Entrez.efetch(db="biosample",id=sra_id, rettype="runinfo").read()

tree = objectify.fromstring(meta_data)
print(tree.BioSample.Attributes.submitter_handle)
```

Comment: You should specify what you want to extract exactly, a list of all tags `Attribute` ? or the text inside some of them ?

Comment: I want the attribute name, that's the values after "harmonized_name=" and the corresponding tag value from all the lines.
For Eg:`<Attribute display_name="sex" harmonized_name="sex" attribute_name="sex">male</Attribute>`
For this line the attribute name is "sex" and the value is "male"

Comment: ok, could you add the code you've tried ? that is what will help other people, and also those who will answer

Comment: `from lxml import objectify

tree = objectify.fromstring(meta_data)
print(tree.BioSample.Attributes.submitter_handle)`
I was trying to do something like this but this won't work since there is no tag under Attributes named  submitter_handle.

Comment: submitter_handle here is the harmonized_name of an attribute

Comment: Please edit the question instead of adding code in comments.

Comment: If you want to find, say, `submitter_handle`, then you can use an XPath search for `./Attributes/Attribute[@display_name="submitter handle"]`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I want to get all the values under the tag Attribute as well as the other tags.

Comment: @VaisakhViswanath, yes, the XPath above returns the whole Attribute, so you can then retrieve whatever you want from it.

Comment: Can I use XPath for retrieving values from other tags such as **Id is_primary** ?